# How to change editor bottom border line color in xamarin crossplatform

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Here is my renderer code

```
public  class CustomEditorControlRenderer: EditorRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var _element = e.NewElement as EditorControl;

            this.Control.Hint = _element.Placeholder;

            Control.SetHintTextColor(_element.PlaceholderColor.ToAndroid());
            this.Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            this.Control.SetCursorVisible(true);              

            Control.Background.SetColorFilter(Android.Graphics.Color.White, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);

        }

      }       

    }
```

`Control.Background.SetColorFilter(Android.Graphics.Color.White, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);` is not working

Comment: I am solved my problem using "et_underline_unselected.xml"  code  with some changes.Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a renderer, what about wrapping you editor in a StackLayout with a padding?
This should do the job:

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
      <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black" Padding="1">
          <Editor BackgroundColor="White" />
      </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selector` to achieve it:

### C# code

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    if (Control!= null)
    {
        //Control.SetBackground(null);
        Control.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.et_underline_selector);
    }

}
```

### .xml files

Put these files into your `drawable` folder:

`et_underline_selector.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/et_underline_unselected"/>
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/et_underline_selected"/>
</selector>
```

`et_underline_unselected.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
      android:bottom="0dp"
      android:left="-2dp"
      android:right="-2dp"
      android:top="-2dp">
    <shape>
      <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
      <stroke
          android:width="1dp"
          android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
      <padding android:bottom="4dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

`et_underline_selected.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
      android:bottom="0dp"
      android:left="-2dp"
      android:right="-2dp"
      android:top="-2dp">
    <shape>
      <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
      <stroke
          android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light"
          android:width="2dp" />
      <padding android:bottom="4dp" />

    </shape>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```